# Ubuntu Installation Partition Screen is completely blank

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Win7 machine. When I start the installer, I end up at the partition screen that has no options for where to install. I've not been able to find another example where this is completely blank. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to upload a picture to show this, but I cannot as I'm a new member.

Comment: You can take a picture and include the link to it. Or simply transcribe it.

Answer (score 0):

The installer does not shows Any HDD because Your HP BIOS prevents the HDD. You have to disable this option by going into Bios Setttings and Harddisk configuration. After that You will able to see your HDD in Ubuntu Installer.

```
 To go into BIOS press F10 at start...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. From what else I've read, I need the hard drive to be AHCI which I've changed it to.

I do have a specific menu option that is 'Storage' -> 'Configuration', but there's nothing editable in that menu.